# What is the difference between attr_accessible(*attributes) & attr_protected(*attributes)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What is the difference between `attr_accessible(*attributes)` & `attr_protected(*attributes)`? Examples would be nice.

I see many developers use these in their models. I googled for the differences, but I don't get exactly what they are. What is the importance and its necessity in different scenarios?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

`attr_accessible` ([documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_accessible/class)) says "the specified attributes are accessible and all others are protected" (think of it as [whitelisting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist).)

whereas

`attr_protected` ([documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_protected/class)) says "the specified attributes are protected and all others are accessible" (think of it as [blacklisting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blacklist).)

A *protected attribute* is one that can only be modified explicitly (e.g. via *attribute=*) and can't be updated via  mass assignment (e.g. using `model.update_attributes` or by passing attributes to `new`). The behaviour upon an attempt to update a protected attribute via mass assignment depends on the `mass_assignment_sanitizer` setting (see the update below).

The classic example would be if a `User` model had an `is_admin` attribute you could protect that attribute to prevent form submissions that would allow any user to be set as an administrator.

example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # explicitly protect is_admin, any new attributes added to the model
  # in future will be unprotected so we need to remember to come back
  # and add any other sensitive attributes here in the future
  attr_protected :is_admin
end
```

compared with:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # explicitly unprotect name and bio, any new attributes added to the model
  # in the future will need to be listed here if we want them to be accessible
  attr_accessible :name, :bio
end
```

Now, assuming `is_admin` attribute is protected:

```
> u = User.find_by_name('mikej')
> u.is_admin?
false
> u.update_attributes(:name => 'new name', :is_admin => true)
> u.is_admin?
false
> u.name
"new name" 
> u.is_admin = true # setting it explicitly
> u.save
> u.is_admin?
true
```

---

Update: Later versions of Rails introduced the concept of a *mass assignment sanitizer* to control the behaviour upon attempts to update protected attributes via mass assignment. In Rails 3.2 and later this can be controlled by setting `mass_assignment_sanitizer` in config. The default is to just log the attempts and allow code execution to continue, but the standard environment config for development sets this to `:strict` which raises as exception on an attempt to update a protected attribute.

Comment: No, you can only use one or the other. If you include both in a class then you won't see an error when the class is first loaded but it will probably manifest itself as `NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!` when you try to use the class.

Comment: @mikej:- thanx excellent answer 'll like to know more on this pls provide if u know any link etc.cheer's

Comment: @Salil take a look at this blog post: http://b.lesseverything.com/2008/3/11/use-attr_protected-or-we-will-hack-you for another example and post another comment or start a new question if you have any specific things you'd like to know.

Answer (score 7):

attr_accessible is a white list for mass-assignment ...

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base #has attributes foo and bar
  attr_accessible :foo
end
f = Foo.new :foo => "test", :bar => "test"
f.foo #=> "test"
f.bar #=> nil
```

attr_proteceted is a black list for mass assignment ...

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base #has attributes foo and bar
  attr_protected :bar
end
f = Foo.new :foo => "test", :bar => "test"
f.foo #=> "test"
f.bar #=> nil
```