# Devise - mass assignment error when changing other users passwords in specific password change page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In my RoR application I'm using devise and the client requires a bit of customisation - basically he requires that the administrator be able to change passwords of other users and that the password change page be different than the page to edit profile details. I've set up custom actions to handle this namely my own change_password action in users controller.

```
Users Controller Actions
def change_password
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update_password # I post to this
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes!(params[:user])
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end
```

Heres the routes.rb entries

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations]                                          
    as :user do
      get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'    
      put 'users' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'            
    end
  resources :users
...

  match "/users/:id/change_password" =>"users#change_password", :as=>:change_password_user, :via=>:get
  match "/users/:id/update_password" => "users#update_password", :as=>:update_password_user, :via=>:post
```

And this is my users model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable, :registerable,
  devise :database_authenticatable, #:registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :role_ids, :as => :admin
  attr_protected :username, :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  validates_uniqueness_of :username
  validates_presence_of :username, :email

  validates_uniqueness_of :email
end
```

however I keep getting this mass attributes assignment error

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: password, password_confirmation
```

the weird thing is that I've set all these attributes to accessible_protected. I can edit other users details but can't edit their passwords. Whats going on here?

Comment: Not sure it's the solution but if you're changing someone else's password, how come you have @user = current user in thr edit action. Looks correct in the update action. Might be nothing.

Comment: sorry I pasted the wrong code there- fixed it - but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting `attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation` instead of `attr_protected :password, :password_confirmation`? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2652919/429758

Comment: I did that initially but then it wasnt allowing me to change the user profile - I have a custom action for the user profile here as well

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you can fix this problem. I'll try to explain a few.

I think the key to your problem is that you are mixing up the `MassAssignmentSecurity` roles. You've defined a `Whitelist` for the `admin` role and a `Blacklist` for the `default` role. The error says that you tried to assign something that was on the `Blacklist` for the `default` role.

Since you are defining different roles, I assume you probably want to fix it this way:

Change your admin `Whitelist`

```
attr_accessible :role_ids, :password, :password_confirmation, as: :admin
```

Then assign as the admin:

```
if @user.update_attributes!(params[:user], as: :admin)
```

(If your controller action includes fields other than the password fields, this may cause new violations.)

A different option is to stick to the default role. You can bypass security a couple ways.

The first option which I don't recommend is to not pass the password and password confirmation as part of the `User` params, and send them separately in your view. You can then manually set those fields like so:

```
@user.assign_attributes(params[:user])
@user.password = params[:password]
@user.password_confirmation = params[:password_confirmation]
if @user.save!
```

However, it's even easier to do the following to just skip protection:

```
@user.assign_attributes(params[:user], without_protection: true)
if @user.save!
```

For more information, this guide is fairly good:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment

I hope that helps.