# Password update gives mass assignment error with Devise security extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, mass-assignment

We are trying to use [Devise Security Extension](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension) gem to use the :password_archivable feature, to prevent users from reusing old passwords. Whenever we try to change the user's password on the website we get a mass assignment error.

Part of our model:

```
class User < Person
  rolify
  devise :database_authenticatable, #...
         :password_archivable
 #attr_accessible :encrypted_password, :password_salt
  ...
end
```

Part of our controller:

```
class HealthPromotersController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  ...
  def update
    ...
    respond_to do |format|
      if @health_promoter.update_attributes(params[:health_promoter])
        sign_in(@health_promoter, :bypass => true) if @current_user.id == @health_promoter.id

        format.html { redirect_to @health_promoter, notice: 'Health Promoter was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @health_promoter.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

When we go to the edit health_promoter page and input a password and password_confirmation, Devise Security Extension fails with a Mass Assignment error for encrypted_password and password_salt when the [password_archivable.rb](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension/blob/master/lib/devise_security_extension/models/password_archivable.rb) code tries to set:

```
 OldPassword.new(old_password_params)
```

`ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error at /health_promoters/1
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: encrypted_password, password_salt`

We tried adding :encrypted_password and :password_salt to the attr_accessible list, to no avail.  The Devise documentation (github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/3d9dea39b2978e3168604ccda956fb6ec17c5e27/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb) says we can use :force_except or :except but it is not clear how or where this should be specified.

We are using the following versions:
Ruby 2.0.0p451, Rails 3.2.19, Devise 3.2.4, Devise Security Extension 0.8.0

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read this? Not sure if it's the same thing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334036/devise-mass-assignment-error-when-changing-other-users-passwords-in-specific-p?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the devise security extension to 0.7.2, for a quick fix, as it works