# Lack of attributes declared on model classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Using Rails 3 (haven't confirmed whether this is different in Rails 2.x), when you use a generator to create a model, eg:

```
rails generate model Person first_name:string last_name:string
```

It doesn't declare the first_name or last_name attributes on the Person model class it creates. I understand that it still works, i.e. the migration creates the fields in the DB and I can set them at runtime due to dynamic language magic. However, I think of a model class as being a sort of "documentation" for what attributes are available for the model. Therefore it's strange to me that the generator doesn't add them.

I've been adding:

```
attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name
```

to my model classes. Or even better, [attr_accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652907/what-is-difference-between-attr-accessibleattributes-attr-protectedattrib/2652919#2652919). But even then, it doesn't make clear what the data type is.

I'm just curious as to what others thoughts are on:

1. Why doesn't the generator do this by default?
2. Do you add accessors yourself? Why or why not?
3. Bonus: can I specify the data type somehow?

**Update**: Ok forget the attr_accessor then, I see why this doesn't make sense. Let's assume I should add attr_accessible instead. Still would like people's thoughts on the questions above though.

Comment: `schema.rb` can be used to find the attributes of a model

Answer (score 0):

***Don't*** add `attr_accessor` for the model attributes - you'll be breaking their intended functionality.  `attr_accessible` is fine and generally recommended, but they are only needed for white-listing for [mass-assignment protection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment) purposes.  You don't need to add anything to your models for the getters/setters to work; ActiveRecord does this for you by examining your database schema.

If you want 'documentation' in your models, check out the [annotate](http://rubygems.org/gems/annotate) gem that will autogenerate field information as comments at the top of your models/fixtures/tests/specs.

Comment: Ok I adjusted my post above. You're right, attr_accessor doesn't make sense. But if the practice is to leave the model blank, where would somebody who wants to use my model class look to figure out what attributes are available? The database? The migration? Isn't that sort of wrong?

Comment: The /db/schema.rb file holds a snapshot of your schema as ActiveRecord sees it (wrapped as a single migration), and you can likely configure your IDE to show this info to you while inside your model class - RubyMine does this by default.  If you prefer seeing it written out in your model, then I recommend using 'annotate' - that's why it was built :).