# is necessary mass assignment protection in a model without controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-oauth, rails-activerecord, mass-assignment

I have a model like this:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :page_id, :name, :page_url, :username
end
```

and it doesn't have a related controller, but in an other controller I'm executing this code:

```
fgraph  = Koala::Facebook::API.new(ftoken)

@pages = fgraph.fql_query("select XXX from pages where xxx")

@pages.each do |p|

    newpage = Page.find_or_initialize_by_page_id("#{p["page_id"]}")
    newpage.update_attributes(
      name: p["name"],
      username: p["username"],
      page_url: p["page_url"]
      )
end
```

this last line updates the data of my model with facebook data. I supose it's imposible to attack with mass-assign because I've obtained the info inside the action method, but I'm really begginer with rails and I would like to confirm if my supossition is true.

Comment: If that method modifies any attributes apart from the ones mentioned in the list, rails would throw an error. If not, all would be working fine. It has got nothing to do with controller. You cannot modify non-accessible attributes from anywhere in your code base.

Comment: this method is modifying all the attributes from Page class. They have to be accesible because I need to write in this class some info from facebook. In the code there is not a PagesController or pages#update method, only this.

Comment: This is an excellent answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652907/what-is-difference-between-attr-accessibleattributes-attr-protectedattrib/2652919#2652919][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652907/what-is-difference-between-attr-accessibleattributes-attr-protectedattrib/2652919#2652919

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. 
It is true that whitelisted attributes **can be** updated from anywhere else, with mass-assignment.

`update_attributes` is a rails method which takes in a hash of attr-value pairs and tries to apply that to the object and save. Before the `save` returns successfully, all `model validations` are run to see if the save operation can be executed.

Since in your case, the update is targeting the whitelisted fields, your method runs fine. The day your method tries to update any other attribute, say, `date_of_birth`, the method will fail saying `date_of_birth` cannot be mass-updated.

For the sake of safety of the data, you should use [rails-sanitizers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/HTML/Sanitizer.html) preferably at the write time, or at the read time. This will ensure

1. Data presented is readable and not ugly(which some user inputs tend to be)
2. Data in the tables is html-safe
3. Does not cause any kind of [code-injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).